# mysql multi threading for a single query

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I have big db of size 8GB and having 9 million contacts in this db. When we try to retrieve all contacts, it takes nearly 1 or 2 hour (in some cases result in timeout) to retreive all contacts for the excecution for a single query. Also I have 8 CPU and 24GB RAM, Xeon Processor, the mysql process won't distribute accross the 8 CPU's. My question is that, does we can enable multi threading for a single query.

Awaiting for your Reply

Answer (score 3):

Mysql doesn't support multi threading for a single query.

Just a few days ago there was a good post on mysqlperformanceblog where it explains advantages of doing parallel queries. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/01/07/increasing-slow-query-performance-with-parallel-query-execution/

If you're just retrieving the contacts with a simple query it's also likely IO might be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much volume your contact represent, or what query you use, but 1 or 2 hours seems a bit too much for that kind of information.

Either the I/O is the bottleneck, either your query need tuning.